# Some features stopped working after the Lumia Denim update?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, lumia-denim-update

After installing Lumia Denim v12419.341 in Lumia 520, I found several bugs in the Touch app where I can't see an option for double tap to wake.

When I turn off vibration for navigation key it tells me to restart but when I press restart it keeps on showing restarting and never restart.

In display I can't find colour profile ?! All this was available just before the .341 update.

I tried a hard reset of the phone 4 times but it hasn't fixed the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the OS and firmware version of Settings > About?

Comment: Also, make sure all apps are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Use Lumia software recovery tool https://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/LumiaSoftwareRecoveryToolInstaller.exe to reinstall the firmware on your phone from the scratch. Do a backup first.